# Why Python3 not see the installed module 'pandas' when running from PHP page?

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

I am working on Linux Ubuntu. I installed python and when I run it through the terminal is working perfect.

However, I have a php web page that exec the python script. When it run the python script from PHP page it return this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

The code that run python script is:

```
exec("/usr/bin/python3 ./myscript.py", $output, $return_var);
```

I run the commands `which python3` and `pip3 list` on both terminal and through PHP page.

`which python3` on the terminal return:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

`pip3 list` on the terminal return:
a list of packages and I can see the pandas

```
 pandas                 1.4.3
```

`which python3` from PHP return:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

`pip3 list` from PHP return:
a list of packages and I cannot see the pandas in it.

Why it different? how could I install panads so the python3 can see it through PHP pages?

Note: I am running the same code on Mac and it runs without any issues from both terminal and php.

Comment: probabily PHP is using another python envirovment without pandas

Comment: how could I check that? and how could I change it to use the same python environment

Comment: how you launch the Python code on your PHP? Could you post an example?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, I install apache and put all my php pages inside /var/www/html . then in the browser I run it using localhost as URL

Comment: I mean, how do your Python from PHP

Comment: I edited the question to include the code of running the python through php

Answer (score 1):

Try installing pandas from the php page (and run it only once.) Do that by adding the following line in the php code.

```
echo shell_exec('pip3 install pandas');
```

The 'echo' should not be necessary but you will see if it downloaded correctly. Also using pip instead of pip3 should work.